# Third party user access to Azure environment

Tags: azure, permissions, subscription

I have an requirement where I need to give access to Azure subscription and resources to third party company. basically we are outsourcing the work to them. I am looking for the best possible way to do it.

is it possible to add the third party team as the guest uses to the Azure subscription/resource group and give them contribute permission? Or there is any other way in terms of security to provide the access to third party users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to add the third party team as the guest uses to the Azure subscription/resource group and give them contribute permission?

You provide the access to a `third-party company` for `Azure subscription` or resources, add the third-party team as guest users in Azure Active Directory and grant them appropriate permissions by following steps.

1. Invite the external user to Azure AD
2. Create a `Dynamic Group` for moving all external user to that group automatically based on condition.

> Ex: user.userType -contains "Guest or Company name = "your company name"

[image]

3. Assign the role to the group on the `Azure subscription or resource group`.

[image]

> Note: Assign the role to the group on the Azure subscription or resource group.

4. External users are successfully moved to that group based on the condition.

[image]

5. The Contributor role has been assigned at the Subscription scope.

[image]

6. Once you provide access to external users, all external users can access Azure resources.

Refer: [Assign Azure roles to external guest users using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-external-users) for more details.